# Rewrite URL extensions

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a url like

```
http://www.example.com/keyword-city.php
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/keyword-city/
```

Is there any easy solution to do that?

Edit:
I need a dynamic solution for that. Example:

```
http://www.example.com/keyword1-city.php
http://www.example.com/keyword2-city.php
http://www.example.com/keyword3-city.php
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/keyword1-city/
http://www.example.com/keyword2-city/
http://www.example.com/keyword3-city/
```

Answer (score 2):

Add .htaccess file with your project add this code in this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /.php
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. is there a way to do this with variables? i got about 200 files with that pattern "keyword-city.php", "keyword1-city.php" and i want to rewrite all to "/keyword-city/

Comment: all file you want to rewrite as the file /keyword-city/ and if any others file like a "keyword-city1.php" now you can rewrite without extension, but its complicated to all file rewrite like a "keyword-city"

Comment: i dont really understand your comment. is there no way to replace the ".php" to "/" on all pages with the pattern text-text.php ?

Answer (score -1):

This is easy:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/keyword-city.php';
echo str_replace('.php', '/', $url);
```

Comment: The OP needs a solution in mod-rewrite, not in PHP.